# Can I get my Touch Bar to play sounds to acknowledge my Touch Bar key presses?

Tags: macbook-pro, touch-bar, haptic-feedback

I love my MBP and the Touch Bar is pretty cool, but sometimes I find I’m second-guessing myself. Did I press the ESC key or not? Did I press that function key? Well you get the idea. There’s just no physical feedback and sometimes I keep tapping where I think something is, but it’s not!

I know there's no tactile feedback, but then it hit me - maybe there’s a setting somewhere for sound. You know, like the beeps you here when pressing buttons on some devices.

My guess is this is just not possible, but before I make the suggestion to Apple I wanna make sure!

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually you’re in luck. A while back I came across [Haptic Touch Bar](https://www.haptictouchbar.com).

This software not only offers the *sound* feedback you’re looking for, but actually provides tactile feedback by activating the trackpad magnets to vibrate the MBP when you're using the Touch Bar.

**NOTE:** I am not affiliated with the developer or this software in any way.

Comment: Thank you my man! So I found a full review at http://www.idownloadblog.com/2017/10/14/haptic-feedback-macbook-pro-touch-bar/ and have downloaded the free version trial to test it out. Seems like there was some issue when it first came out so I wanna test  it first!

Comment: Yes, good idea! Always good to try/test software first if you can. :)

Answer (score 7):

There is a FOSS alternative out there: [HapticKey](https://github.com/niw/HapticKey).
The latest release can be gotten on [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/):

```
brew cask install haptickey
```

Similarly as Haptic Touch Bar this software will both enable tactile feedback and sound.

Comment: Always favoring foss, I've not yet tried the originally linked Haptic Touch Bar application, but I am really happy with how this HapticKey open source one performs.  It's not a physical ESC key, but it will go a long way toward a viable workaround!  Thanks for sharing it here!